# Is it possible to get phone number of user after login with google

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, google-signin

I am using firebaseui to log in users with google login. I am getting all other details but phoneNumber is returning null. Does google allow to get a phone number after google log in? or should I have to go for phone authentication to get phone number of users
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`User.phoneNumber` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#phone-number) is only populated when you use a phone number to sign in to Firebase. From that documentation:

> This is null if the user has no phone credential linked to the account.

Firebase Authentication does not request the phone number from users' Google accounts.